# Listview does not automatically refresh after getting list data from DataStore

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which I populate with data from DataStore or from my local database.

I am checking some condition that will determine whether I will fetch data from the DataStore or database. When I fetch from the database the ListView automatically refreshes itself, but when I fetch from the DataStore it does not. I then have to click my TextView, which is below ListView, and when I click it the soft keyboard appears and then my ListView is populated with data from DataStore.

My activity that has the ListView:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xyz);

    list_View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.data_listView);
    list_View.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    list_View.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new Selector());

    adapter = new MyAdapter(context,Long.valueOf(id),isOnline());
    list_View.setAdapter(adapter);
    list_View.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            list_View.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
        }

   LoadDataTask ldt = new LoadDataTask();
    ldt.execute("123456789");
}

 private void loadDataFromDataStore(final Long contactId){
    final ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();;
    d("loadingdataFromDatasore");

    GetDataTask task = new GetDataTask(new ApiTask.ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void successHook(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof GetDataResponse) {
                GetDataResponse res = (GetDataResponse) o;
                if (res.getData() != null && res.getData().getItems() != null) {
                    for (ListDataItem i : res.getData().getItems()) {
                        Data dp = new Data(i.getPosition(), i.getMessage(), i.getDateCreated(),i.getMessageId(),1);
                        adapter.addFromOtherThread(dp);
                    }

                }

                d("Messages loaded from server: " + adapter.getCount());
            }

        }
}

public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void> {
         @Override
    protected  Void doInBackground(String... params){

        if(isOnline && isFirstTime){
         loadDataFromDataStore(Long.valueOf(params[0]));
        }else{
          //load from database
        }

        return null;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

My adapter class that extends BaseAdapter (I have removed unnecessary code for this question):

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Data>data_list;

public DataAdapter(){
    data_list = new ArrayList<>();
}

 public void addFromOtherThread(Data object) {
    data_list.add(object);
}
```

What am I missing that is making listview not to automatically refresh itself even after calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`?

Comment: Yes you have to use notifyDatasetChanged() after adding data in your list.

Comment: @Avi           i dint understand your comment

Comment: You are using `notifyDataSetChanged` is your `doInBackground` method that causing the problem i guess. For that what you can do is to return the data you are getting from the `successHook` method and then use `addFromOtherThread` method in your `onPostExecution` with `notifyDataSetChanged` which would show new data to the listview.

Comment: You are using if(isOnline && isFirstTime) , Have you check the condition is it true or didn't allowed to add data in adapter.It may be chance it is getting false and data is not actually adding in adapter.

Comment: @Avi  am trying to implement your second comment. on the case of my `if(isOnline && isFirstTime)`. condition is true because am able to download data from the appstore. even  my log `d("Messages loaded from server: " + adapter.getCount());` shows me total data downloaded. let me see if your second comment will work and i will tell you

Comment: @Avi still din't work. its giving me headache. to make matter worse, i don't know who downvoted my question without giving any reason

Comment: @Avi there is something i have discovered. `loadDataFromDataStore` finishes its work after `onPostExecute()`! don't understand why.

Comment: Where are you executing GetDataTask task;

Comment: K The problem with your code is that from do In background you are executing a another thread which response is not reliable when to come.Remove async task and simply update the adapter in onSuccessHook method.

Comment: @Avi           GetDataTask is a class responsible for calling a backend module method which return data from entities.

Comment: Please look at below provided answer.

Comment: I am up voting your question as you are doing wrong implementation and your code need improvement. May be I am not explain you well but someone can do it. You have to understand the flow of your code which causing you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xyz);

        list_View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.data_listView);
        list_View.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        list_View.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new Selector());

        adapter = new MyAdapter(context,Long.valueOf(id),isOnline());
        list_View.setAdapter(adapter);
        list_View.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                list_View.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
    loadDataFromDataStore("123456789")

    }

     private void loadDataFromDataStore(final Long contactId){
        final ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();;
        d("loadingdataFromDatasore");

        new GetDataTask(new ApiTask.ResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void successHook(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof GetDataResponse) {
                    GetDataResponse res = (GetDataResponse) o;
                    if (res.getData() != null && res.getData().getItems() != null) {
                        for (ListDataItem i : res.getData().getItems()) {
                            Data dp = new Data(i.getPosition(), i.getMessage(), i.getDateCreated(),i.getMessageId(),1);
                            adapter.addFromOtherThread(dp);
                        }

                    }    
                    d("Messages loaded from server: " +      adapter.getCount());
adapter.notifyDatasetChanges();
                }

            }
    }.execute();
}
```

GetDataTask should work on background internally you don't need to starts a AsyncTask from here.

If you want to use AsyncTask then your AsyncTask should wait for the result from GetDataTask which it is not doing in your code implementation.
I don't know which kind of framework you are using to making api call but your implementation seems to look wrong.

I have write the code on assumption bases if your GetDataTask is a AsyncTask or some background processor it will work perfectly.

Comment: But i guess that would not work because its still in `doInBackground` method

Comment: @Avi           i don't know what to say but man, **you saved my day**. this is the correct solution. i nevwr thought calling an asyn task inside another asyn task can cause malfunction.  `GetDataTask` is an asyn task **which extends another asyn task**.  `GetDataTask` calls a backend class which loads entities from datastore and deliver results to `new ApiTask.ResultListener()`. Thanks Avi

Answer (score 2):

change :

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

to:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list_View.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Let me know if more clarification is required by commenting below.

Comment: You dont need to `setAdapter` if you are doing `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: @Sangeeta      still it does't change

Comment: @Clairvoyant   what should i do because Sangeeta answer din't work?

Comment: have you checked data is coming or not in the adapter?

Comment: @Sangeeta  yes in my log, it tells me 2 data have been loaded. **i have to click textview which triggers softkeyboard and as a result my listview is refreshed**

Comment: @Sangeeta      do you have any other suggestion

Comment: @Clairvoyant    there is something i have discovered. loadDataFromDataStore finishes its work after `onPostExecute()` and yet it's called in `doinBackground` method. thus doen't update listview with it's data. don't understand why.